# Does an equivalent of <include> exist to reuse designs/layouts in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In normal Xml activity building exists an `<include>` property that allows reuse designs in different activities like top and bottom bars. I have been searching for something like that in Jetpack Compose but I cannot find anything.
I know that @Composable functions work as independent elements that can be used whenever you want, but if I'd used this approach these elements would be reloaded whenever the activity changed.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need: just call the function where you've defined the design/layout you want to use.

In traditional Android layouts, the `<include>` tag is needed because XML doesn't have any concept of "calling" another XML file.  In Compose, every layout and every component is a function, so you can simply call the function wherever you want to reuse that layout.

There's almost no difference between including the contents of a composable function directly inside another composable function and calling that composable function (there are slight differences in the runtime's internal bookkeeping, but generally nothing that users of Compose need to worry about).

In fact, you can mark a composable function `inline` to achieve this more directly and have the contents inlined into the calling function.

Comment: the design problem with this approach is if i just call the @Composable function, by example a Bottombar,  on every activity where i need it, the bar will be reloaded every time and I just want to reload the rest of the content, will be similar to have an UI layer "on top" of the rest of the application.

Comment: That is true of `<include>` as well: it would be reinflated in every layout that it is used in.

Comment: @IgnacioMiranda: "the bar will be reloaded every time and I just want to reload the rest of the content" -- that is not how Compose works. Compose is a declarative UI system. Basically, everything is "reloaded every time", and the Compose runtime determines how to change what is rendered to match the result of the recomposition.

Comment: @CommonsWare so is it impossible to implement something like xml fragments but written in Compose?

Comment: @IgnacioMiranda: Yes, you can. Ryan explained this in his answer. You simply think that "these elements would be reloaded whenever the activity changed" is a problem, and it is not. Compose, through the use of `remember` and related properties, can determine which composables need to be re-evaluated based upon state changes. And Compose can determine what that means in terms of rendering the UI. Generally, we stop worrying about "these elements would be reloaded whenever the activity changed" and simply describe the UI that we want, using composable functions.